# How to open a PDF document in newtab from navigation in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, reactive-programming

How to open a pdf document in newtab from navigation in ReactJS?

Menu's:

```
{
    key:  'yourServerObligMenu',
    name: 'Your Service Obligation ',
    path: '/serviceObligation',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip',
    active: false
},
```

routes:

```
import YourServiceObligationPage from './pages/YourServiceObligation'
<Route path='serviceObligation' component={YourServiceObligationPage} />
```

pages:

```
import ServiceObligationContent from '../components/serviceObligation/ServiceObligationContent';

export default class YourServiceObligation extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>  
                <ServiceObligationContent/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

component:

```
export default class ServiceObligationContent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Link to="/documents/YourServiceObligation.pdf"  target="_blank">


        );
    }
}
```

**I am unable to open a document in a newtab when I click on navbar menu** `serviceobligation`

Comment: And what happens when you click it ?

Comment: You probably don't want `<Link>` component here because the document itself is probably served from the server. Try using `<a>` tag instead.

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? as discussed here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2188, this should not be an issue now